# While iteration over numpy array, I can't call methods of objects stored in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iterator, vpython

first question asked in StackOverflow, so tips on how to 'ask' better are most welcome.

Basic Goal of this part of the code:
A number of balls (no_balls) move in random directions.

I am trying to move from python lists to numpy arrays for better performance. Here is the reduced code.

Basic Problem:
My iterator gives me objects of type ndarray not vpy.sphere , therefore calling sphere.pos on the objects I am iterating over fails.
Or is this not possible, since Numpy is build for numbers?? Alternatives for performance?

```
import vpython as vpy
import numpy as np

#Create and Fill numpy array with random size balls
balls = np.empty([no_ball], dtype=vpy.sphere)

with np.nditer(balls, flags=['refs_ok'], op_flags=['readwrite']) as b_it:
    debug_msg(len(b_it))
    for b in b_it:
        b[...] = (vpy.sphere( radius=random_in_range(ball_min_r,ball_max_r), 
                              opacity=0.8, 
                              color=random_RGB(), 
                              pos=vpy.vector(0,0,0),))
    debug_msg('populated balls list')

#Main Loop
debug_msg('Starting Main Loop')
while True:
    vpy.rate(30)
            
            
with np.nditer(balls, flags=['refs_ok'], op_flags=['readwrite']) as b_it:
    #Main Loop
    debug_msg('Starting Main Loop')
    while True:
        vpy.rate(30)
            
#The actual loop manipulates the position but the problem is that I can't access the   position of the sphere objects. Type returns nd.array for b
        for b in b_it:
           debug_msg(type(b[...]))
           debug_msg(b[...].pos)
```

```
#Above outputs
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path", line 93, in <module>
    debug_msg(b[...].pos)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'pos'
```

How do I call methods and members of objects in the array. And on a sidenote, why do I need to call b[...] instead of b, seems obsolete.

Comment: Using `numpy` like this will probably make your performance *worse*. Question, what does `print(balls.dtype)` show?

Comment: `b` from `nditer` is a 0d array containing a `vpy` object.  `b.item().pos` may work.  But `nditer` doesn't improve iteration speed over an object dtype array.  And using an object dtype array is not an imprivement over a list.

Comment: As you suggest, numpy is really about collections of numbers, and if you're storing collections of objects, numpy loses many of its advantages. Usually, the conceptual change I end up making in moving a system to numpy is if I have a class that represents a Ball that has `x` that's a float, I remove the Ball class and make a class for Balls and that has a `x` that's a numpy array with the position of all the balls. This way you get large arrays of numbers, which is what numpy wants.

Comment: I see from all alternatives, that numpy might not be the way to go.  
@tom10 I am not sure I understand that correctly. Are you suggesting to make a class which contains a list of balls whose position reference a numpy array filled with that data?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That returns 'object' What is an effective way to iterate and manipulate/ call methods of a large number of objects?

Comment: Yes, I think we are saying the same thing (although I'm not 100% sure). As for whether to use numpy, it does come with some design tradeoffs. But the speed advantage can easily be 100 - 1000x. It depends what you need.

Answer (score 2):

A simple class:

```
In [149]: class Foo():
     ...:     def __init__(self,i):
     ...:         self.i = i
     ...:     def __repr__(self):
     ...:         return f'<FOO {self.i}>'
     ...: 
In [150]: Foo(323)
Out[150]: <FOO 323>
```

A list of such objects:

```
In [151]: alist = [Foo(i) for i in range(10)]
```

An equivalent object dtype array:

```
In [152]: arr = np.array(alist)
In [153]: arr.dtype
Out[153]: dtype('O')
In [154]: arr
Out[154]: 
array([<FOO 0>, <FOO 1>, <FOO 2>, <FOO 3>, <FOO 4>, <FOO 5>, <FOO 6>,
       <FOO 7>, <FOO 8>, <FOO 9>], dtype=object)
```

Fetching the attribute from the list:

```
In [155]: [f.i for f in alist]
Out[155]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
In [156]: timeit [f.i for f in alist]
826 ns ± 8.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

and from the array (slower):

```
In [157]: timeit [f.i for f in arr]
1.66 µs ± 15.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Using `nditer` - you studied the docs enough to get the flags right, but didn't grasp that `b` is an array, not a `Foo`:

```
In [158]: with np.nditer(arr, flags=['refs_ok'], op_flags=['readwrite']) as b_it:
     ...:     for b in b_it:
     ...:         print(b, b.dtype, b.shape, b.item())
     ...: 
<FOO 0> object () <FOO 0>
<FOO 1> object () <FOO 1>
<FOO 2> object () <FOO 2>
<FOO 3> object () <FOO 3>
<FOO 4> object () <FOO 4>
<FOO 5> object () <FOO 5>
<FOO 6> object () <FOO 6>
<FOO 7> object () <FOO 7>
<FOO 8> object () <FOO 8>
<FOO 9> object () <FOO 9>
```

Fetching a list of the attribute:

```
In [159]: res = []
     ...: with np.nditer(arr, flags=['refs_ok'], op_flags=['readwrite']) as b_it:
     ...:     for b in b_it:
     ...:         res.append(b.item().i)
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [160]: res
Out[160]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And a poor timing:

```
In [161]: %%timeit
     ...: res = []
     ...: with np.nditer(arr, flags=['refs_ok'], op_flags=['readwrite']) as b_it:
     ...:     for b in b_it:
     ...:         res.append(b.item().i)
     ...: 

7.25 µs ± 60.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

One of the cleaner ways of performing an action on elements of an object array is with `frompyfunc`:

```
In [162]: f = np.frompyfunc(lambda b:b.i,1,1)
In [163]: f(arr)
Out[163]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=object)
In [164]: timeit f(arr)
2.1 µs ± 8.58 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Still slower than the iteration, though if we want an array instead of just a list, it is better than:

```
In [165]: timeit np.array([f.i for f in arr])
5.79 µs ± 21.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The `nditer` docs need a stronger performance disclaimer.  `nditer` when used in `c` or `cython` code is useful and fast, but when accessed via Python code it is inferior to more obvious alternatives.  It's extra bells-n-whistles may be useful in some cases, but mostly I see it as a bridge to properly compiled code, not as an end of itself.

At the heart of the performance issue is that `Foo` is a Python class.  So accessing the `i` attribute has to use the full Python referencing system.  It can't make use of any of the fast compiled `numpy` numeric methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That clarifies a lot. So the item()  function would solve it, but the performance is bad the way I use it either way. I did dig quite deep into the nditer docs actually and never came across item()
I will therefore go look for better approaches. Thanks

Comment: An alternative to `item` is `b[()]`.  `b[...]` is the way of setting the value of such a 0d array.  In any case the iteration in `nditer` is a trickier than it appears on the surface.